# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack" - versions don't appear to conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I'm trying to update a Rails project from Rails 4.2.7 to 5.2. I get the following message from `bundle update`:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    haml-rails was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)

    rails (= 5.2) was resolved to 5.2.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.0)
```

It doesn't look to me like there should be any conflict, unless I don't understand the version requirements correctly. Rails wants actionpack 5.2.0, haml-rails wants actionpack >= 4.0.1. 5.2.0 is greater than 4.0.1. Where's the conflict?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I never did discover why I was getting that message about incompatible versions, but I resolved my issue by commenting out `gem 'haml-rails'` in my Gemfile, running `bundle update`, reinstating `gem 'haml-rails'`, and running `bundle update` again.

Comment: I still don't know why this happens 